# PostgreSQL connection string without Database - Error using NPgSQL

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'm getting an error when I connect to PgSQL when I omit the Database from the connection string using Npgsql (.net)

- Error: {"3D000: database \"j.smith\" does not exist"}
- Failing connection string: *Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};*
- Working connection string: *Server={0};Port={1};User
  Id={2};Password={3};Database=postgres*

I understand that without the Database parameter, Pg will default to Database=User, but I'd rather not specify the database. Is there any way to do this?

Otherwise, does the 'postgres' DB exist on every PgSQL installation and can any user that can logon always connect to it?

Looks like there was a bug for Npgsql relating to this, but was fixed in 3.0.1. I'm using 3.1.8.
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/703

Thanks.
Ark

Comment: did you create `"j.smith"` db?

Comment: j.smith is the user.

Comment: if you dont include Database will try to connect to `user_name_db` so either give a generic database already or create one with with the name of the user

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for... You already know that when you omit the database, the username is used (as is standard with PostgreSQL tools), what else are you expecting Npgsql to do?

Comment: Essentially, I want to connect to the database to validate the credentials and then query from the system catalog for the database list. My application has a 'Test Connection' button by which to do this. If I can expect the 'postgres' database to always exist, then I'm happy to add this to the connection string. Is this the case?

Comment: The postgresql and template1 database are not always reachable (security wise).